# How to create measure to find sum of max completion?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new with power bi desktop.
I have a table with three columns Phase name, task name, and completion.
see the picture for more details.

[image]

and I am trying to create a measure to calculate the sum of completion phase from each max task completion.

> For Example completion of phase 1= Max completion of task 1+ Max
>   completion of task 2+Max completion of task 3. 
>   So, IT Will return 70+20+10=100
>   And Imagin this for more phases and task.

I will be glad for your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new table where you get the Max:

```
MaxDur = GROUPBY(Phase; Phase[Phase];Phase[Task];"MaxValue"; MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(); Phase[Value]))
```

Result below:

[image]